# Powershell pipelines null values to own function

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

My script should do something with every .pdf file (what exactly doesn't matter). For this, I have written a function that gets called like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.pdf | foreach { $_.FullName} | ProcessPdfCreator
```

I tried to rework the `foreach` loop that my function gets called in the braces, but that doesn't change anything. Anway my script looks like this:

```
Function ProcessPdfCreator {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string]$filepath
    )

    Begin{}
    Process{
        #Do something with $filepath
    }
    End {}
}
```

My Tests so far have resulted that the `$filepath` variable always is null; but I used `echo $_.FullName` to cofirm that the name is correct before the piping/function calling.

PS: I am forced to work with **PowerShell 2.0** on this PC, but as far as I can tell this code should work here nonetheless.

Comment: Which tests? How did you determine that the value of `$filepath` is null?

Comment: The error message said something about cannot bind the argument to "path" because it's null or empty (the computer is set to German and so was the error message).

I did a `echo ($filepath -eq $null) in the function to verify this.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem you describe with the code you posted. I tested on a clean default install of Windows 7 32-bit by echoing `$filepath` in the `Process{}` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.pdf | select -ExpandProperty FullName | ProcessPdfCreator
```

Additionaly, remove casting to `[string]`

```
Function ProcessPdfCreator {
[cmdletbinding()]
Param (
    [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
    $filepath
)
Begin{
}
Process{
    #Do something with $filepath
}

End {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I take it that the ForEach loop isn't necessary with piping?

Comment: No, it is not. The pipe with advanced lifecycle can process tables, however 2.0 wasn't that flexible as later versions, hence it is safer to clean the input table (this is why select with expand) and remove casting (because the input is a table).

Comment: There is no effective difference between `foreach { $_.FullName }` and `select -Expand FullName`, so I fail to see why one should work while the other doesn't.